# Is it Out can be used for passing a reference type (i.e) Objects?

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, out, ref

Consider the following example, here **int i** is passed for the reference.

My question is, Can i pass a reference type to **out**? like object (i.e) **static void sum(out OutExample oe)**

```
class OutExample
{
   static void Sum(out int i)
   {
      i = 5;
   }
   static void Main(String[] args)
   {
     int val;
     Sum(out val);
     Console.WriteLine(val);
     Console.Read();
   }
}
```

Now the below code having some error,

```
class OutExample
{
  int a;
   static void Sum(out OutExample oe)
   {
    oe.a = 5;
   }
   static void Main(String[] args)
   {
    int b;
    OutExample oe1=new OutExample();
    Sum(out oe);
    oe.b=null;
    Console.WriteLine(oe.b);
    Console.Read();
   }
   }
```

Finally Got the Answer!

```
class OutExample
{
int a;
int b;

static void Sum(out OutExample oe)
 {
   oe = new OutExample();
   oe.a = 5;
 }

static void Main(String[] args)
{ 
   OutExample oe = null; 
   Sum(out oe);
   oe.b = 10;
   Console.WriteLine(oe.a);
   Console.WriteLine(oe.b);
   Console.Read();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: ya i tried the above code, its working well. @MarcGravell

Comment: ya i tried the above code, its working well.@BenjaminDiele

Comment: @Balaji so... did you try `static void sum(out OutExample oe)` ? what happened?

Comment: ya, but it is showing some error!                                                    The out parameter 'oe' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

Comment: @Balaji that happens for *all* `out` parameters if you don't assign a value to it; if you remove the `i=5`, the same will happen in the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new `OutExample` inside the `Sum` method:

```
class OutExample
{
   int a;
   int b;

   static void Sum(out OutExample oe)
   {
       oe = new OutExample();
       oe.a = 5;
   }

   static void Main(String[] args)
   { 
       OutExample oe = null; 
       Sum(out oe);
       oe.b = 10;
       Console.WriteLine(oe.a);
       Console.WriteLine(oe.b);
       Console.Read();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok But the **b** is underlined red of telling, Class doesn't contain a definition for **b**

Comment: This is true. You defined `b` inside the `Main` scope so it's a local variable and not a class field like the `a`.

Comment: the definition of **b** is within the **Main** only, then how can it be a non local variable?

Comment: It is a local variable but only in the scope of the `Main` method and not the entire class. I modified the example

Comment: Fantastic man, its working well...

Answer (score 1):

Yes...

```
static void Sum(out OutExample oe)
{
    oe = null;
    // or: oe = new OutExample();
}
class OutExample {}
```

Comment: If it is **null** how can i use it in **Main()**?

Comment: @Balaji that is up to `Main`! and of course, `Sum` could set it to a non-null instance

Comment: can u please fully edit the above pgm and your answer too?

Answer (score 1):

I  would suggest you to rethink something.
Reference type are a reference to a storage location. Passing it in `out` you are passing a reference to this references. Why don't you pass directly by `ref`?

Comment: I think @Balaji is using `out` because he wanted to learn how it works. Questions whether it's a good or a bad practice will come later :-)